# SQL Server 2008 R2 Nested IFs Not Executing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement

This has been driving me crazy for over an hour.  I'm sure I'm overlooking something idiotic. Feel free to mock me, just tell me why the last "ELSE" doesn't execute when @TransactionType is neither 'insert' nor 'update' (it's 'delete', just FYI):

```
IF @TransactionType = 'insert'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [GLOBAL_TEST_INDICATOR_AUDIT](
        [ScheduleID]
        ,[CTSNumber]
        ,[TestNumber]
        ,[GlobalTestIndicator]
        ,[CreatedBy]
        ,[CreatedOn]
        ,[ModifiedBy]
        ,[ModifiedOn] 
        ,[TransactionType] 
        )
    VALUES(
        @ScheduleID,
        @CTSNumber, 
        @TestGroupNumber,
        @GlobalTestIndicator,
        @User,  -- Created By
        GETDATE(),  -- Created On
        NULL,   -- No Modified By for Insert
        NULL,   -- No Modified On for Insert
        @TransactionType
        )
    IF @@ERROR <> 0 RETURN 10 -- Indicates SQL INSERT Operation Failed! 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN
    IF @TransactionType = 'update'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [GLOBAL_TEST_INDICATOR_AUDIT]
            SET [ModifiedBy] = @User,
                [ModifiedOn] =  GETDATE(),
                [GlobalTestIndicator] = @GlobalTestIndicator,
                [TransactionType] = @TransactionType
            WHERE [ScheduleID] = @ScheduleID
            IF @@ERROR <> 0 RETURN 20 -- Indicates SQL UPDATE Operation Failed!
        END  
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [GLOBAL_TEST_INDICATOR_AUDIT]
            SET [ModifiedBy] = @User,
                [ModifiedOn] =  GETDATE(),
                [TransactionType] = @TransactionType
            WHERE [ScheduleID] = @ScheduleID
            IF @@ERROR <> 0 RETURN 30 -- Indicates SQL UPDATE Operation Failed!
        END
END
```

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, what's the value of @ScheduleID and are you sure there is a record in GLOBAL_TEST_INDICATOR_AUDIT that matches that value?

Comment: Put a `print` statement to make sure it's going inside the last ELSE block.

Comment: I think you have your IF ELSE structure wrong, remove the "ELSE" before the "BEGIN" above the line of "IF @TransactionType = 'update', also use print statements to make sure it is hitting where you need it to, and to back out of it just do 3 statments IF = Insert BEGIN, END, then IF = Update BEGIN, END...IF = Delete BEGIN END

Comment: squillman, you got me - there was no record matching the value of @ScheduleID in another table, GLOBAL_TEST_INDICATOR_BILLING, to match the one in GLOBAL_TEST_INDICATOR_AUDIT, so it would never update.  Obviously it's time to walk away for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Your second-last `UPDATE`:

```
        UPDATE [GLOBAL_TEST_INDICATOR_AUDIT]
        SET [ModifiedBy] = @User,
            [ModifiedOn] =  GETDATE(),
            [GlobalTestIndicator] = @GlobalTestIndicator,
            [TransactionType] = @TransactionType
        WHERE [ScheduleID] = @ScheduleID
```

is almost the same as your last `UPDATE`:

```
        UPDATE [GLOBAL_TEST_INDICATOR_AUDIT]
        SET [ModifiedBy] = @User,
            [ModifiedOn] =  GETDATE(),
            [TransactionType] = @TransactionType
        WHERE [ScheduleID] = @ScheduleID
```

How can you tell the two apart?

I'd suggest putting in a `PRINT` statement to see if your "delete" block is being triggered:

```
IF @TransactionType = 'update'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [GLOBAL_TEST_INDICATOR_AUDIT]
        SET [ModifiedBy] = @User,
            [ModifiedOn] =  GETDATE(),
            [GlobalTestIndicator] = @GlobalTestIndicator,
            [TransactionType] = @TransactionType
        WHERE [ScheduleID] = @ScheduleID
        IF @@ERROR <> 0 RETURN 20 -- Indicates SQL UPDATE Operation Failed!
    END  
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Not insert or update'

        UPDATE [GLOBAL_TEST_INDICATOR_AUDIT]
        SET [ModifiedBy] = @User,
            [ModifiedOn] =  GETDATE(),
            [TransactionType] = @TransactionType
        WHERE [ScheduleID] = @ScheduleID
        IF @@ERROR <> 0 RETURN 30 -- Indicates SQL UPDATE Operation Failed!
    END
```